# Hex file verification inside microcontroller

Tags: hex, microcontroller

As we all know, the hex file is the heart of our application code which will be programmed into the microcontroller's flash memory for execution. My doubt is before the execution of this hex file, will it be verified by a microcontroller or it will just execute once all start-up processes finished?

Comment: Off-topic.  `microcontroller` tag requires a part number.  There are countless microcontroller parts with widely varying capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: Because I don't know all microcontrollers, this is not a complete answer.**

The flashed binary executable will just be executed.

Some microcontrollers check for a certain value at a fixed address to decide whether to start the built-in bootloader or a flashed user program.

If you need the user program to be checked, you will need to implement this yourself. I have worked with such systems, it is quite common, especially in safety-related environments.

---

Concerning the format of hex files:

[Intelhex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX) as well as other format like [SREC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SREC_(file_format)) are human readable text representations of binary data. The common reason for the checksums in these formats is to ensure data consistency during transmission, which was done via unreliable channels back at the time when the formats were invented.

Another advantage is the limitation to 7-bit ASCII characters that can be transferred losslessly via old internet protocols.

However, the "real" contents, the binary data, is stored directly in the flash memory of the microcontrollers. Checksums might be used by the receiving software (for example the bootloader) in the microcontroller when the user program is to be flashed. But after flashing they are gone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If the hex file will not be verified, then why checksum is present at the end of each line. For instance, say the hex file is in intel hex format There will be a lot of lines with hex data. I'll take only one line here.   :10229000104078000080FB008000EB00C802DD00E9 . In this line, the last byte E9 is a checksum of that line. As per your answer, if that is correct, then what will be the use of the checksum data present in every line of hex file.

Comment: @ the busybee: Thanks. I understood the point. From this convo, I came to conclusion with 2 points.

1. Once, flash memory is written with software, there will be no verification further in the microcontroller. If so, after a long time of usage, if the flash memory gets corrupted or damaged due to unwanted reasons, the microcontroller will still work with corrupted flash memory. 

2. Unless there is bootloader software in the microcontroller, there will be no mechanism to verify the checksum of the hex file when burning a program.

Comment: @CNA the intel hex file has a checksum to help with the storage and transfer of the file itself.  but the data is converted to binary and put into the mcu's flash, there is no connection between the file format features and the contents of the mcu.

Comment: @old_timer:  Thanks. So, this is a reason for adding the hex file verification feature in the software, specifically in safety-related environments.

Comment: @CNA yes, if this is safety related, but understand the early code that does the check itself is not checked.  there are cores from arm for example that are safety based with I think two cores that run in parallel or some such thing, I didnt dig into it...